# couchDB sort result array by date if date is stored in an array of integers?

Tags: jquery, json, couchdb, couchdb-futon, nosql

I'm storing couchDB docs and they have an attribute `date` which I want to sort by.

```
{

  ...blahblah...

  "date": [
    2015,
    5,
    16
  ]
}
```

I can't seem to figure out how to make a view that allows me to supply a startdate=[2015,5,1]&enddate=[2015,5,31] query. I want to get the stuff for May (month 5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be as simple as:

```
function (doc) {
  emit(doc.date);
}
```

Then your query needs to be: `start_key=[2015,5,1]&end_key=[2015,5,31]`

Check out the [documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/couchapp/views/intro.html)

Comment: I knew it was something simple. Although I think it's supposed to be `startkey` and `endkey` without underscore, right? thanks for the link.

Comment: You can use either, they're aliases for the same thing. (source: [documentation](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/ddoc/views.html))

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, If the date field specified documents are created in order (that is doc with field date = "2015, 4, 16" was created before the doc with field date = "2015, 4, 20). In that scenario, you can also sort using the timestamp when the document was created.

```
function(doc) { 

emit([doc.created_at,doc.date], doc);
}
```

http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/View_collation

Comment: interesting, except it's not about creation date of the document, but a date stored in it.